# Android Studio ThermoCalc Fahrenheit to Celsius vise versa

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am currently programming in Android Studio creating a "ThermoCalc". Basically I need to covert Fahrenheit to Celsius and vise versa. My issue is my calculations are coming out the same and there is some error in my coding, maybe something where it shouldn't be? Hope someone can help. I am new to coding and slowly learning. Any feedback is appreciated. Thank you

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final EditText etTemp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtTemperature);
    final TextView tvOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblOutput);
    final RadioButton radFahToCelLogic = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radFahToCel);
    final RadioButton radCelToFahLogic = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radCelToFah);

    Button btnConvertLogic = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnConvert);
    btnConvertLogic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            double dblFahrenheit = 0;
            double dblCelcius = (5.0/9) * (dblFahrenheit -32);
            double dblConvertedTemp = 0;
            double dblFahConversion;

            // format
            DecimalFormat dfTenth = new DecimalFormat("#.#");


            if (radFahToCelLogic.isChecked())
            {
                if (dblFahrenheit <= 212)
                {
                    dblConvertedTemp = (5.0/9.0) * (dblFahrenheit - 32);
                    tvOutput.setText (dfTenth.format(dblConvertedTemp));
                }
            }

        }
    });
```

I believe the issue has something to do with my dblFahrenheit being set to "0".

So basically in my emulator with my app running, I have one EditText widget which is where you input the temperature, a TextView widget to display output, and two Radio Buttons located in a RadioGroup.

In my if statement I am checking to see if the inputted temperature is equal to or less than 212. If it is then I need to convert my inputted temperature from Fahrenheit to Celsius.

When running my app, no matter what number I put in the EditText(Temperature), the answer is always "17.8".

Comment: Welcome to SO. Maybe you should tell us what kind of error you see so as we can help specifically. Giving us the code is good. But we are not a "please debug the code for me" service. .

Comment: Where do you use the input from the user?

Comment: @DanielNugent I'm trying to use the inputted temperature in my if statement. dblFahrenheit is supposed to be the inputted temp by user. I need to rename my variables better once I get the first conversion fixed.

Comment: @JoeyCodes nice of you ! We are really forgiving with people eager to learn and making effort. I'm editing your question, because you don't need to apologize to me. cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you just forgot to use the input.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

final EditText etTemp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtTemperature);
final TextView tvOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblOutput);
final RadioButton radFahToCelLogic = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radFahToCel);
final RadioButton radCelToFahLogic = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radCelToFah);

Button btnConvertLogic = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnConvert);
btnConvertLogic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        double dblFahrenheit = 0;
        double dblCelcius = (5.0/9) * (dblFahrenheit -32);
        double dblConvertedTemp = 0;
        double dblFahConversion;

        // format
        DecimalFormat dfTenth = new DecimalFormat("#.#");


        if (radFahToCelLogic.isChecked())
        {
            String strFah = etTemp.getText().toString();
            if (!strFah.isEmpty()){

              dblFahrenheit = Double.parseDouble(strFah);

              if (dblFahrenheit <= 212)
              {
                dblConvertedTemp = (5.0/9.0) * (dblFahrenheit - 32);
                tvOutput.setText (dfTenth.format(dblConvertedTemp));
              }
            }
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. It seems I forgot to convert my declared dblFahrenheit to a string so it can be used in my calculation. You've helped me complete this app. Both of my conversions are now working and I cleaned up my code a little bit. I am very new to coding but am learning something new everyday and learning from my mistakes. Thanks again Daniel for giving me the boost I needed with this and helping me understand.

Comment: Just did! Thanks again. Great website, I think i'll be visiting here more often to improve on my coding.